# How to open Angular CLI project in Canary instead of default Chrome?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

Angular CLI v6 has an option `ng serve --browser-target`, but I can't find documentation on how to use it to serve a specific browser... Their docs literally say only "Target to serve." with no example and using the full path does not work.

e.g. `ng serve --browser-target '~/Applications/Google\ Chrome\ Canary.app'`

How do I use this to serve dev project to Canary?

p.s. Don't want to change default browser to Canary; only serve current project.